# how to add a new row in table in function [onClick ],and remove this attribute from the all row except the new

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I wrote a code that added a new row, and remove a (onClick) Attribute when i clicked on the existing row in table

```
<table style="vertical-align:middle;margin:20px;" id="table_insert">
 <tr  id="tra" >
  <td >Word :</td><td onClick="insert_tr()"> <input type="text" id='word_text' ></input></td>
  <td>Definition :</td><td><input type="text" id='def_text' ></input></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

this is the function that add a new row, remove onclick attr from the previous and add it to the new added row :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert_tr(){
     $(this).removeAttr('onClick'); //jQuery inside javascript function
     console.log("text:"+$(this).find('td').attr('onClick') ); 
        $('#table_insert').append('<tr onClick="insert_tr()"><td>Word :</td><td > <input type="text" id="word_text" ></input></td><td>Definition :</td><td><input type="text" id="def_text" ></input></td></tr>');
}
</script>
```

but it doesn't work,and on console screen,it prints [text:undefined] ..How can i fix it ?!!

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)`  -- Here this is a **Window Object** and not the Element you are expecting

Pass `this` to the function

```
onClick="insert_tr(this)"
```

/

```
function insert_tr(elem){
     $(elem).removeAttr('onClick'); //jQuery inside javascript function
     // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Because this refers to window and not the current element as it is out of context